# How to convert Visual Studio 2005/2008 project to Visual Studio 6

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any tool to convert Visual Studio 2005/2008 project to Visual Studio 6? Thanks.

Comment: is this a C# or Visual basic project ?

Answer (score 2):

Doubtful. I am pretty sure Microsoft does not have anything like that.

I assume this is a C/C++ project? VS 6 was before .NET.

I guess your best option is to start with a blank VS 6 project and manually add the source files.

After adding the source files, attempting a compile should quickly tell you what library/include folders you need to reference.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft does not support that conversion. But there is some tool to convert from vc7 to vc6 projects. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/prjconverter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of such a tool. Instead, import the individual source files into a new VS6 project.

Answer (score 0):

This make be a long shot here, but on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/sln2mak.aspx), there's an article on converting a solution to a Linux Makefile, and use that make file under VC6...Would this be useful?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.